# Query to group by column and count number of days based on dates

Tags: group-by, postgresql-9.4

Sample data:

```
   id|location|date    
    1|TUNDUMA |16/8/2015
    2|TUNDUMA |16/8/2015
    3|TUNDUMA |17/8/2015
    4|TUNDUMA |18/8/2015
    5|TUNDUMA |19/8/2015
```

Is it possible to count the number of consecutive days for `TUNDUMA`?

Something like:

`TUNDUMA -> 4 days`

Comment: Say there are rows with dates: 16,17,18, 23,24. What should the answer be? Just a row with `'TUNDUMA',3`? Or two rows, one with 3 and one with 2?

Comment: Hi. One result 16 to 24

Comment: So 9 days? Or 5 days? (because these are **not** consecutive dates.)

Comment: 9 days. From first to last date

Comment: So you are looking for the number of days in the range that is defined by the minimum date in a group and the maximum day in a group, regardless of the number of (other) dates that are actually present in the table, correct? Please clarify that **in your question**, because without such a clarification people could be taking your `TUNDUMA -> 4 days` output **as the actual result** for your sample data, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two or more sequences, do you want the larger of the two or the size of the first?

It might be possible to do this in a query, but I don't think so.

An easier way would be to use a stored PL/SQL procedure; use a query that groups by location and date, and loop through the result, adding 1 to a counter for each date that is exactly one larger than the one prior.

Edit: it looks like what you're looking for isn't a sequence, but rather the difference between the maximum and minimum date for each location.

If the column is of `date` type, you can use the difference: `max(date) - min(date)`. If it is a `timestamp`, you have to use `date_part('day', difference)` to get an integer as a result:

```
SELECT LOCATION, date_part('day', ma-mi) + 1 AS LENGTH FROM
(
Select LOCATION, MIN(DATE) as mi, MAX(DATE) as ma
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY LOCATION) as t;
```

or just:

```
SELECT LOCATION, date_part('day', MAX(DATE) - MIN(DATE)) + 1 AS LENGTH 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY LOCATION;
```

Comment: Hi. I would need one for every sequence. Eg. If there was another location I would need the same thing

Comment: What if there are two sequences within the same location? Like 16-17-18 and then 21-22-23-24?

Comment: That would be from 16 to 24

Comment: @Fab That's not a sequence, it's missing 20. If what you're asking for is the difference between the minimum and maximum date for each location, that's a lot easier. Is that what you're looking for?